# typealias LazyVStack for iOS 13

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that I want to maintain iOS 13 support for, but on iOS 14 I want to use the new `LazyVStack` and `LazyHStack`. I was thinking `typealias` would be perfect for this, but wasn't sure how to properly set this up so the alias is used on iOS 13 but not on 14. I tried this, but believe this would make the alias available on iOS 13 and up, so would include it on iOS 14 too.

Is there a way to set the availability to iOS 13 only? Or is there a better way to do this?

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
typealias LazyVStack = VStack
```

Comment: There is certainly a way to set availability to iOS 13; you set it to iOS 14 for an `if` and then use the `else` for iOS 13. But I don't think that's going to help you with some sort of typealias trick. You should just do this the dumb way: two sets of code. Even Superman has to get into his tights one leg at a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is possible wrapper that can be used as regular stack container

```
struct CompatibleVStack<Content> : View where Content : View {
    let alignment: HorizontalAlignment
    let spacing: CGFloat?
    let content: () -> Content

    init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil,
            @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
      Group {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) { // << add more platforms if needed
            LazyVStack(alignment: alignment, spacing: spacing, pinnedViews: [], content:content)
        } else {
            VStack(alignment: alignment, spacing: spacing, content:content)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish this could be done with typealias, but this dose seem to be the best solution.

Comment: I ran into a crash with this code when running on iOS 13, I had to wrap the VStack or LazyVStacks in AnyView

Comment: Try to wrap condition in body into Group as updated (instead of using AnyView)